# Listview item onclick to deliver bundle from database

Tags: android, database, bundle

I made a listview with an onitemclick method to deliver bundle which it get from the database to another activity.

But the other activity didn't get the bundle as I expected, can someone check my code and tell why? thx

> ```
>     mDB = new ChannelDB(this);
>
>     String[] columns = {mDB.KEY_ID, mDB.KEY_POSTER, mDB.KEY_CHANNEL, mDB.KEY_PATH, mDB.KEY_DBLINK};
>     String   table   = mDB.channelS_TABLE;
>
>     c = mDB.getHandle().query(table, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
>
>     startManagingCursor(c);
>
>     SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
>             R.layout.channelview,
>             c,
>             new String[] {mDB.KEY_POSTER, mDB.KEY_CHANNEL, mDB.KEY_DBLINK},
>             new int[] {R.id.poster, R.id.channel, R.id.douban});
>
>     adapter.setViewBinder(new ChannelViewBinder());
>
>     channellist.setAdapter(adapter);
>
>     channellist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
>         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
>                 int position, long id) {
>           c.moveToPosition(position);
>           Intent intent = new Intent();
>             intent.setClass(HDtvs.this,Showlist.class);
>             Bundle bunde = new Bundle();
>             bunde.putString("path",mDB.KEY_PATH);
>             bunde.putString("cname",mDB.KEY_CHANNEL);
>             bunde.putString("dblink",mDB.KEY_DBLINK);
>             /* 将Bundle对象assign给Intent */
>             intent.putExtras(bunde);
>
>             startActivity(intent);
>         }
>     });
> ```

showlist.java

```
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /* 设定layout为newslist.xml */
    setContentView(R.layout.showlist);   
    ChannelName=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cname);
    back=(Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    likebutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.share);

    Intent intent=this.getIntent();
    Bundle bunde = intent.getExtras();

    /* 取得Bundle对象中的数据 */
    String path = bunde.getString("path");
    String title = bunde.getString("cname");
    String dblink = bunde.getString("dblink");

    Bundle bunde2= new Bundle();
    bunde2.putString("dblink",dblink);
    /* 调用getRss()取得解析后的List */
    li=getRss(path);
    ChannelName.setText(title);
    /* 设定自定义的MyAdapter */
    setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,li, bunde2));
    `
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you retrive the data from the `Intent` aswell?

Comment: paste the Showlist activity code

Comment: How is `MyAdapter` defined? Try `Log.i("showlist", "dblink = " + dblink)` and see if the value shows up in `logcat`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(HDtvs.this,Showlist.class);
intent .putExtras("path",mDB.KEY_PATH);
intent .putExtras("cname",mDB.KEY_CHANNEL);
intent .putExtras("dblink",mDB.KEY_DBLINK);
```

and then in your second class get this bundle like this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
path= extras.getString("path");
```

Answer (score 0):

are u sure "putExtras" is right? can u break point at this line :

```
  String path = bunde.getString("path");
```

maybe you put a empty string into buddle？